# Magento2 Ajax change store currency and refresh total on Checkout page when change address

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax, jquery, magento2.4

I want to change the current store currency by ajax and refresh the total when changing the address on the checkout page. I have successfully changed store currency by below code:

```
$this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
```

But problem is that when I am trying to refresh the total then the amount converted as per currency successfully but the currency symbol not changed. Below is the js code of refresh total:

```
cartCache.set('totals',null);
defaultTotal.estimateTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading cart section after change currency `customerData.reload(['cart'], true);`

**Sample code:**

```
define([
    ...
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'
    ...
], function (
    ...
    customerData,
    defaultTotal,
    cartCache
    ...
) {
    'use strict';

    afterChangeCurrency: function () {
        ...
        ...
        customerData.reload(['cart'], true);
        cartCache.set('totals',null);
        defaultTotal.estimateTotals();
    }

});
```

Comment: Hello @Prince, Thanks for this. I tried this but the currency symbol still not change.

Comment: Do you have any other solution regarding this?